# C++ Comparing vector<string> to an array of char and finding elements in vector that contain specific series of indices in the array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, vector

I am a beginner programmer and I am not quite sure how to tackle this issue. What I am trying to do is write a loop that will cycle through every element in the vector of strings, and at each element compare the string to a specific series of chars in the array of chars to see if they contain them

For example take a look at this:

> _ _ _ _ _ _
>   _ _ _ _ _ _
>   _ _ _ G _ _
>   _ _ _ O _ _
>   _ _ _ N _ _
>   _ _ _ E _ _
>   _ _ _ _ _ _
>   _ _ _ _ _ _

Say I read in vertically from the 4th column going down all the characters and store them in the array, so the array would contain {_, _, G, O, N, E, _, _}

And for example say in my vector of strings, there are these words

{BEGONE, ALONG}

How can I cycle through this vector of strings and ensure that each element in the vector the string contains just the letters contained within the array, as the array will contain excess chars.

So after passing through the function, the vector of strings would just contain {BEGONE}

The reason we need to do this is because we are trying to filter out the strings in our vector which do not contain the sub-word represented by the array of chars.

I am not sure if this is the best way to approach this problem in the first place so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the code we have tried so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < preFixedLetterVerticalVect.size(); ++i){
    int k = 0;

    bool playable = true;
    while(k < preFixedLetterVerticalVect.at(i).size()){
        if(preFixedLetterVerticalVect.at(i).at(k) == fixedLetters[k]||(!(isalpha(fixedLetters[k])))){
            k++;
        }
        else{
            playable = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!playable){
        preFixedLetterVerticalVect.erase(preFixedLetterVerticalVect.begin() + i);

    }
}
```

Thank you for your time, please let me know if the question is unclear or if anything can be improved in any way.

Comment: Why store the excess `_` characters in the array you will be using to test with?  Just store the letters.

Comment: I suggest you tackle the problem one step at a time.  You have a string, you have another string.  Write a function that takes two strings, and tests if all characters in the second string are in the first string.  Once you have that working, then just use that function in the loop.  You don't even need to do this in your current program -- just create a simple `main` function, another function that checks, and call the function using various inputs.